# Cannot find shared library even with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set, while setting ld.so.conf works

Tags: linux, g++, shared-libraries

The program fails to find a shared library even with the path of the library included in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH (also exported correctly). However, after I add the path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and then execute `ldconfig`, the program runs without error.

Why does this happen?

Comment: _also exported correctly_ - there needs to be a proof of that.

Comment: Also, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not work for setuid programs.

Comment: The correct way, of course, is to set `rpath` when linking.